# Where is a model's __past_status = None field stored?

Tags: django, django-models

I have something that works but I don't quite understand why;

Some time ago I started using one great solution from SO, and now I'm using it in more places. The solution is;
you have a model eg

```
class Membership(models.Model):
    user_cancelled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    __past_status = None

def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        if self.pk:
            if self.user_cancelled != self.__past_status and self.user_cancelled:
                ....
    except:
        pass
    super(Membership, self).save(force_insert, force_update, *args, **kwargs)
    self.__past_status = self.user_cancelled
```

it works perfect and allows me to achieve what I wansn't quite able to using signals. What I don't understand is where the `"__past_status"` field's value is stored as it does not appear in migrations and therefore there is no db record of it. But it works. I would appreciate any explanation or hint.

Comment: it is not stored it is just attribute on class

Comment: But I know it is stored as it works correctly which it wouldn't if it stayed as None (I added 2 last lines in code)

Comment: You are setting it yourself at the end of the save method. (This would only exist for the current instance if you make a query and get the same instance you would notice it has this attribute as None.)

Comment: 1) I am unable to check its value as when I check the __dict__ of an instance, it is not included 2) Consider following: Instance's user_cancelled was False and I change it to True - code in (....) executes. When I save the instance again (still with True) code does not get executed (which is would if the is the __past_status wouldn't store value of True) - so it is not set back to None